# Python IDLE GUI not starting

Tags: windows-8.1, python-idle

I feel like I have been coming the internet for days with absolutely no result.
I have taken some web programming classes, and would like to learn some python, just because programming is wicked interesting altogether, and have run into a fairly large hurdle given my experience.

the problem is this: Python.exe (or is is more properly pythonw.exe?) v3.3.3, running on windows 8.1 used to launch fine. Typed up a simple program to roll various sided die, worked out well. Then I changed the key bindings for 'Run Module' from 'ctrl+f5' to 'crtl+alt+spacebar.'

As soon as I did this IDLE crashed and so did the shell. Now the process will not run AT ALL. I cannot access it through the desktop icon to go back and revert the settings. I also attempted to look at the .def files and change it from there but could not find the 'run module' command. It looked like all the key bindings in the .def files were for the shell.

When I double click, nothing, when I run as admin, nothing. run from the start menu, nothing. I uninstalled and re-installed, rebooted, everything low tech I can think of. Now i'm out of my element and could use one of you brilliant social programmers!!

I've found information about checking with some tool called 'Windows Process Manager' some stuff about what to do with the CMD prompt (something about a path problem ...it intuitivly sounds like I very well could have created a 'path problem' but I'm not 100% I know what that is exactly).

I'm sorry for the lack of links, the pages were farther back in my browsing history than I expected. Hopefully i'm not asking an instant many down vote question here, most of the resources online are for either an older version of windows, Lunix, or an older version of python (which is actually where the path problem hint came from)

Thanks any and all greatly for any time spend reading/answering.
Immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find file HOME/.idlerc/config-keys.cfg, where on Win7 HOME would be 'C:/Users/yourloginname', and delete the key binding or, if there is nothing else in the file or nothing you want to keep, the whole file.

If you were to run Idle from a console with `python -m idlelib`, you would probably see an error message.  (Yes, you were probably running with pythonw, as when using the start menu or icon.  This works better in 3.4.2 and I am working or more improvements.)

I do not know the specific reason for your crash.  I set Zoom-height to --space, restarted, and it works, no problem.